# KeyListener wont work in my JFrame on java while trying to run graphics

Tags: java, graphics

My KeyListener doesn't do anything when I press a key heres the KeyListener

```
private class KeyListen implements KeyListener
    {

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            switch(e.getKeyCode())
            {
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    current.movePiece(-1*BLOCK_SIZE, 0);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                    current.movePiece(BLOCK_SIZE, 0);
                    break;
            }
            repaint();
            System.out.println("Pressed");
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
    }
```

heres the line that adds it in my JPanel

```
this.addKeyListener(new KeyListen());
```

I pressed all the keys on my keyboard and was expecting the words "pressed" to be printed to the terminal or for my block to update but that implementation isn't shown

Comment: The `JPanel` has to be in focus for the `KeyListener` to work.  Use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead.

Comment: A quick search of "my `KeyListener` doesn't work" would quickly lead you to the conclusion that `KeyListener`s are an inappropriate solution for what you're trying to achieve and instead, you should be using [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which will solve the short comings of `KeyListener`s in this use case.  Any other solution is a hack around an otherwise solvable problem and should be avoid

Comment: i strongly advise to take that approach from @MadProgrammer serious, that would be the proper way to handle Keyboard Input!